# Onclick return confirm not working in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using the simple javascript confirm code:

```
function test_confirm (str)
{
    str = (str == '0')? 'Are you sure?' : str

    return (confirm(str))? true : false
}
```

`<a href="http://example.com" onclick="return test_confirm(0)">Test</a>`

This usually works except when I use Jquery Mobile the `OK` and `Cancel` button both proceeds to the URL. The expected behavior is the `Cancel` button should not proceed to the URL.

i.e., I use Jquery Mobile by adding the following in the html `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything I should be aware of to make the javascript `confirm()` function work in Jquery Mobile?

---

**Update for Phill Pafford:**

It does work on plain HTML but this is actually what I'm doing and it doesn't work after redirecting to the same page using PHP's `header('location:')`:

The page `list` contains:

`<a href="list/delete/1" class="customClick" data-str="0">Delete 1</a>`

`<a href="list/delete/2" class="customClick" data-str="0">Delete 2</a>`

The `list/delete` action contains something like this:

```
$rest->delete($id);
header('location: http://example.com/list');
```

As you can see after clicking the URL `list/delete/1` the delete procedure will go on then redirect back to the `list` page. That's where it starts to not work.

As soon as the redirection happens the confirm dialog doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

- http://jsfiddle.net/8CDc5/1/

JS

```
$('.customClick').on('click', function() {
    var str = $(this).attr('data-str');
    str = (str == '0')? 'Are you sure?' : str;

    return (confirm(str))? true : false;
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/8CDc5/" class="customClick" data-str="0">Test</a>​
```

Comment: I tried it. It works only on the first instance of the anchor tag. If you have many `<a href="http://example.com" class="customClick" data-str="0">Test</a>`, only the first click works. I tried disabling Jquery Mobile again, all works. So I guess there's something weird about Jquery Mobile.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8CDc5/2/ or are you saying after you click ok/yes/confirm after the redirect it's not working? as that's a different issue

Comment: It does work on basic examples. I updated my question to explain what's happening to me. I think it's something to do with rest and redirection.

Comment: I will accept this since it works even though my situation required different solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, appears like "return false;" was not stopping propagation and the link was followed anyway. Solved it by explicitly stopping propagation before returning false.

```
function test_confirm (e, str)
{
    str = (str == '0')? 'Are you sure?' : str

    if (!confirm(str)) {            
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


<a href="http://example.com" onclick="var e=arguments[0] || window.event; return test_confirm(e,0)">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute

> data-ajax="false"

```
<a data-ajax="false" href="http://example.com" onclick="return test_confirm(0)">Test</a>
```